# Downloading a webform JSON object list in Firefox 26

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm forced to use an old firefox version 26. I have the below code working perfectly on firefox 72, way more recent, I know. While stepping through the download function, I realize my problem has something to do with the a.click(). While comparing the debugging consoles between browsers I don't notice any differences in the function, but the a.click() isn't triggering the saveAs popup.

Here is the json list format, which has indices equal to n select box elements.

```
testn:{
  val: "pass",
  desc: "test description"}
```

JS

```
jsonData = $("#myform").serializeArray();
function download(content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    }
if (confirm("Save results to <SCRIPT_PATH_LOCATION>")){
    download(JSON.stringify(jsonData), 'webform.results.json', 'text/plain');
} else {
    return false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Modern convenience allowed me to get away with not adequately appending the new element, "a" onto the webform.

JS

```
jsonData = $("#myform").serializeArray();
function download(content, fileName, contentType) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
  //Insert these
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
  //Insert complete
    var file = new Blob([content], {type: contentType});
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    }
if (confirm("Save results to <SCRIPT_PATH_LOCATION>")){
    download(JSON.stringify(jsonData), 'webform.results.json', 'text/plain');
} else {
    return false
    }
```